# Warning in Expo Router - Layout children must be of type Screen, all other children are ignored

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, expo-router, clerk

When I was trying to make folder structure type routes and handling authentication in the main _layout.tsx file and then navigating to different folder route on the basis if the user is authenticated or not.
[code...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2q7O.png)

I am using clerk provider

The warning - **Layout children must be of type Screen, all other children are ignored. To use custom children, create a custom . Update Layout Route at: "app/_layout"**

Is there any way to solve this warning?

```
      <Stack>
        <SignedIn>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="(signin)"
            options={{
              headerShadowVisible: false,
              headerTitle: "",
              header: () => <View style={{ height: 50 }}></View>,
            }}
          />
        </SignedIn>
        <SignedOut>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="(signout)"
            options={{
              headerShadowVisible: false,
              headerTitle: "",
              header: () => <View style={{ height: 50 }}></View>,
            }}
          />
        </SignedOut>
      </Stack>
```

This is the code that I used